# Versioned items causing obstructions in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, ankhsvn, svn-merge

I'm using the VisualSVN server, with TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN in Visual Studio.

I have a Trunk to which some devs on other teams are commiting various small changes on a regular basis.

I have a Branch on which a fairly major new development is being built.  As a regular weekly routine I've been merging the Trunk into this Branch.  All seems to be going ok.

I've come to do another such Merge from Trunk into this Branch and I'm getting truck loads of:-

> The last merge operation tried to add the directory 'nameoffolder', but it was already added locally.

However these are folders that are versioned and have been in the Trunk and Branch for quite some time.

I get a similar thing with files:-

> The last merge operation tried to add the file 'QueueCleanUp.ashx', but it was obstructed in the working copy.

This seems to be widespread accross the whole branch, the vast majority are not to do with anything that the Branch team are working on.

Anyone seen this before?  How can I resolve this lot without masses of work?

Comment: Is the behavior the same when doing the operations from TortoiseSVN directly? I have seen weird error messages when commiting from Ankh which are mostly resolved by performing the same operation from TortoiseSVN directly.

Comment: I've listed Ankh for information only, I only use Ankh to be informed about file status inside VS and the odd single file commit.  For anything large like Merge or a significant Commit I always use TortoiseSVN.

Comment: I wonder why you do this. AnkhSvn has a far better understanding about what files should or shouldn't be committed, because the various project systems in Visual Studio indicate what files should be versioned. The best TortoiseSvn can do is filter based on filename/extension.

Answer (score 1):

In AnkhSVN there's a way to update with the `allow unversioned obstructions` check on. To do this open `View -> Pending Changes`, from here select the `Update` dropdown, and select `Update to specific revision...`. In the dialog that comes up, make sure `Latest Revision` is selected and check `Allow Unversioned Obstructions`.

I'm sure there's a similar option in TortoiseSvn, but I don't have that installed myself, so I can't check.

The commandline equivalent is the `--force` switch to the update command:

```
svn update --force c:\myproject
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I might give that a go to see what results but I'm somewhat nervous about it since the items "obstructed" are already versioned which is to say the least very weird.

Comment: To explains what happens when you force it to update with obstructions is that your new files (that don't have a BASE revision, ie the version without your current changes) get a BASE revision (the changes made by someone else). The file in your working copy will not change. After updating those files will be modified, and you can use a diff tool to see what your changes mean on top of the other person's changes.